# Allow Flash content in Chrome 69 running via chromedriver

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Does anybody know how to enable Flash plugin in Chrome 69.
I use chromedriver 2.41 with java selenium bindings.
I've tried with

```
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins", 1);
prefs.put("profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player", 1);
prefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player", 1);
```

but with no luck.
I've also tried to compare chrome profile preferences with disallowed/allowed flash for particular site and then tried with:

```
            Map<String, Object> site = new HashMap<>();
            Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
            Map<String, Object> setting = new HashMap<>();
            setting.put("flashPreviouslyChanged", true);
            values.put("last_modified", "13180613213099316");
            values.put("setting", setting);
            site.put("http://my.site,*", values);
            prefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.flash_data", site);
```

but it won't work as well.

I've also tried to run with profile specified via

```
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=" + profileDir);
```

but since this white list setting becomes 'ephemeral' in Chrome 69 it also won't work.

Is there any method to run my automation in Chrome with flash support?

Comment: Have you done some research? Like https://www.ghacks.net/2018/08/24/chrome-69-makes-flash-use-annoying/ ?

Comment: I've read this, but in terms of test automation how can I deal with it? The app which I want to test uses flash as a shell for html5 content, so I can't login to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everyone for answers.

I finally have found the solution. In order to enable flash progrmatically since Chrome 69 we have to do 2 things:

1. Disable Ephemeral Flash Permissions (to enable list of allowed for
   Flash sites) and
2. Add all sites to that list.

See the following code on Java:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
// disable ephemeral flash permissions flag
options.addArguments("--disable-features=EnableEphemeralFlashPermission");
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
// Enable flash for all sites for Chrome 69
prefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.setting", 1);

options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
nestedDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: any idea why this is not working for me?
I'm still getting the prompt for the "enable/install flash".

Comment: This helped us a lot, even we are not using chromedriver for our testing. We needed the third step: upgrade flash to 31.

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue want to know what is the nestedDriver?

Comment: EnableEphemeralFlashPermission can no longer be disabled (since Chrome 71).

Answer (score 3):

Given the flag `--disable-features=EnableEphemeralFlashPermission` has been removed in Chrome 71 which severely cripples Flash test automation I would like to share our solution.

```
public class FlashPolicyHelper {

    private final ChromeDriver driver;

    public FlashPolicyHelper(ChromeDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public FlashPolicyHelper addSite(String site) {
        this.driver.get("chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=" + site);
        WebElement root1 = driver.findElement(By.tagName("settings-ui"));
        WebElement shadowRoot1 = expandRootElement(root1);
        WebElement root2 = shadowRoot1.findElement(getByIdentifier("id=container"));
        WebElement main = root2.findElement(getByIdentifier("id=main"));
        WebElement shadowRoot3 = expandRootElement(main);
        WebElement shadowRoot4 = shadowRoot3.findElement(getByIdentifier("class=showing-subpage"));
        WebElement shadowRoot5 = expandRootElement(shadowRoot4);
        WebElement shadowRoot6 = shadowRoot5.findElement(getByIdentifier("id=advancedPage"));
        WebElement shadowRoot7 = shadowRoot6.findElement(By.tagName("settings-privacy-page"));
        WebElement shadowRoot8 = expandRootElement(shadowRoot7);
        WebElement shadowRoot9 = shadowRoot8.findElement(getByIdentifier("id=pages"));
        WebElement shadowRoot10 = shadowRoot9.findElement(By.tagName("settings-subpage"));
        WebElement shadowRoot11 = shadowRoot10.findElement(By.tagName("site-details"));
        WebElement shadowRoot12 = expandRootElement(shadowRoot11);
        WebElement shadowRoot13 = shadowRoot12.findElement(By.id("plugins"));
        WebElement shadowRoot14 = expandRootElement(shadowRoot13);
        new Select(shadowRoot14.findElement(By.id("permission"))).selectByValue("allow");
        return this;
    }

    private By getByIdentifier(String identifier) {
        String[] identifiers = identifier.split("=");

        return identifiers[0].equals("id") ? By.id(identifiers[1]) :
                By.className(identifiers[1]);
    }

    private WebElement expandRootElement(WebElement element) {
        return (WebElement) driver.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot",element);
    }
}
```

The helper should be called after instantiating the ChromeDriver.

```
 driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
 new FlashPolicyHelper(driver).addSite("https://your.site").addSite("https://another.site");
```

Comment: There is a solution to allow Flash using chrome policies: https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#PluginsAllowedForUrls . See my answer here for details for Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53707777/10320142

Comment: Unfortunately Chrome policies are not an option for us but I'm sure that would help someone.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Input this URL in Chrome: chrome://flags/
2. On search inputbox, digit: ephemeral flash
3. Choose "disabled" option.

This will not ask to run Flash Player for further sessions in Chrome 69.

Comment: No longer works. Google removed the 'ephemeral flash' option in Chrome 71.

Answer (score 2):

Python3 version for Chrome 74. Converted from the Java version of @JohnoCrawford above.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

def add_flash_site(driver, web_url):
    def expand_root_element(element):
        return driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element)

    driver.get("chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=" + web_url)
    root1 = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "settings-ui")
    shadow_root1 = expand_root_element(root1)
    root2 = shadow_root1.find_element(By.ID, "container")
    root3 = root2.find_element(By.ID, "main")
    shadow_root3 = expand_root_element(root3)
    root4 = shadow_root3.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "showing-subpage")
    shadow_root4 = expand_root_element(root4)
    root5 = shadow_root4.find_element(By.ID, "advancedPage")
    root6 = root5.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "settings-privacy-page")
    shadow_root6 = expand_root_element(root6)
    root7 = shadow_root6.find_element(By.ID, "pages")
    root8 = root7.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "settings-subpage")
    root9 = root8.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "site-details")
    shadow_root9 = expand_root_element(root9)
    root10 = shadow_root9.find_element(By.ID, "plugins")
    shadow_root10 = expand_root_element(root10)
    root11 = shadow_root10.find_element(By.ID, "permission")
    Select(root11).select_by_value("allow")
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 69 recently released does not allow sites (URLs) to be permanently added (enabled) via `chrome://settings/content/flash` as was the case for previous versions of Flash Player.   However, a URL can be *temporarily* enabled for the current sesison by clicking on the lock icon to the left of the location bar, then choose **Site Settings**, and then enable Flash Player.

This policy forces users of Flash Player to re-configure their permission settings every session, which makes it *less convenient* to use Flash Player.  That is apparently by design.

Fortunately, the **Microsoft Edge** browser does *not* have this policy.  Like Chrome, Edge runs Flash Player.  However, unlike Chrome, it persists the permission settings and does *not* inconvenience the user.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for @JohnoCrawford, i wrote a python code by referring to his java code.

```py
from urllib import quote_plus as url_quoteplus
from urlparse import urlsplit
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By as WebBy
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select as WebSelect

    def allow_flash(driver, url):
        def _base_url(url):
            if url.find("://")==-1:
                url = "http://{}".format(url)
            urls = urlsplit(url)
            return "{}://{}".format(urls.scheme, urls.netloc)

        def _shadow_root(driver, element):
            return driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element)

        base_url = _base_url(url)
        driver.get("chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site={}".format(url_quoteplus(base_url)))

        root1 = driver.find_element(WebBy.TAG_NAME, "settings-ui")
        shadow_root1 = _shadow_root(driver, root1)
        root2 = shadow_root1.find_element(WebBy.ID, "container")
        root3 = root2.find_element(WebBy.ID, "main")
        shadow_root3 = _shadow_root(driver, root3)
        root4 = shadow_root3.find_element(WebBy.CLASS_NAME, "showing-subpage")
        shadow_root4 = _shadow_root(driver, root4)
        root5 = shadow_root4.find_element(WebBy.ID, "advancedPage")
        root6 = root5.find_element(WebBy.TAG_NAME, "settings-privacy-page")
        shadow_root6 = _shadow_root(driver, root6)
        root7 = shadow_root6.find_element(WebBy.ID, "pages")
        root8 = root7.find_element(WebBy.TAG_NAME, "settings-subpage")
        root9 = root8.find_element(WebBy.TAG_NAME, "site-details")
        shadow_root9 = _shadow_root(driver, root9)
        root10 = shadow_root9.find_element(WebBy.ID, "plugins")  # Flash
        shadow_root10 = _shadow_root(driver, root10)
        root11 = shadow_root10.find_element(WebBy.ID, "permission")
        WebSelect(root11).select_by_value("allow")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I saw many methods here is not work for Chrome 71, I would like to share the solution in C# that I am using:

```cs
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
List<string> allowFlashUrls = new List<string>() {
    "*.testing1.com",
    "*.testing2.com",
};
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.managed_plugins_allowed_for_urls", config.ChromeConfig.AllowFlashUrls);
ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
// Then run your test using chromeDriver
```

By setting `profile.managed_plugins_allowed_for_urls` will force Chrome the allow run Flash in the domain declare in `allowFlashUrls` list. Not tested but it should allow Flash to all site by adding `http://*` and `https://` to allow Flash list.

Answer (score 0):

I handled this by going into the settings for the website before I ran my test and doing selenium actions such as below:

```
     public void SetFlashForURL (string yourWebsiteURL) {
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(string.Format("chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site={0}", yourWebsiteURL));
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
                    if (yourWebsiteURL.Contains("https"))
                    {
                        actions.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
                        actions.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
                        actions.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
                        actions.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
                    }
                    actions.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
                    actions.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
                    actions.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
                    actions.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Down);
                    actions.Build().Perform(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**My solution for C#**

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-features=EnableEphemeralFlashPermission");
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference(
          "profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player", 1);
var capability = (DesiredCapabilities)chromeOptions.ToCapabilities();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @RodolphoSilva answer with links:

1 - Input link:  **chrome://flags/#enable-ephemeral-flash-permission**

2 - Change to "**Disabled**"

3 - Click "**RELAUNCH NOW**" button

4 - Input link: **chrome://settings/content/flash?search=flash**

5 - Now you can add or block sites to use flash

@RodolphoSilva - Many thanks for your great answer!

Comment: No longer works. The enable-ephemeral-flash option was removed in Chrome 71.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else needs it, here's how to do the same thing in a Protractor config:

```
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
    args: ['--disable-features=EnableEphemeralFlashPermission'],
    prefs: {
      "profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player": 1,
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-features=EnableEphemeralFlashPermission");
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
    prefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player",1);
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("some url");
```

Comment: please add some brief that what you did special with the cod?

Answer (score 0):

Enable flash in chromedriver using robotframework

Credits: @BaiJiFeiLong

Save following code as `flash_helper.py`

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By as WebBy
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select as WebSelect

def allow_flash(url):

  seleniumlib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')
  driver = seleniumlib.driver

  def _shadow_root(driver, element):
    return driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element)

  driver.get("chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site={}".format(url))

  root1 = driver.find_element(WebBy.TAG_NAME, "settings-ui")
  shadow_root1 = _shadow_root(driver, root1)
  root2 = shadow_root1.find_element(WebBy.ID, "container")
  root3 = root2.find_element(WebBy.ID, "main")
  shadow_root3 = _shadow_root(driver, root3)
  root4 = shadow_root3.find_element(WebBy.CLASS_NAME, "showing-subpage")
  shadow_root4 = _shadow_root(driver, root4)
  root5 = shadow_root4.find_element(WebBy.ID, "advancedPage")
  root6 = root5.find_element(WebBy.TAG_NAME, "settings-privacy-page")
  shadow_root6 = _shadow_root(driver, root6)
  root7 = shadow_root6.find_element(WebBy.ID, "pages")
  root8 = root7.find_element(WebBy.TAG_NAME, "settings-subpage")
  root9 = root8.find_element(WebBy.TAG_NAME, "site-details")
  shadow_root9 = _shadow_root(driver, root9)
  root10 = shadow_root9.find_element(WebBy.ID, "plugins")  # Flash
  shadow_root10 = _shadow_root(driver, root10)
  root11 = shadow_root10.find_element(WebBy.ID, "permission")
  WebSelect(root11).select_by_value("allow")
```

Use above method as keyword in robotframework

save following code as `test.robot`

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    flash_helper.py

*** Test Case ***
Allow Flash In Chrome
    Open Browser    https://www.google.com    chrome

    # go to chrome settings and enable flash
    ${CURRENT_URL}    Get Location
    Allow Flash    ${CURRENT_URL}

    # revert to previous page
    Go To   ${CURRENT_URL}

   # now Flash is enabled in chrome!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `EnableEphemeralFlashPermission` can no longer be disabled in Chrome 71+ versions, here's a slightly modified version of @JohnoCrawford code that works for Chrome 81:

```
def add_flash_site(driver, web_url):
    def expand_root_element(element):
        return driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element)

    driver.get("chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=" + web_url)
    root1 = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "settings-ui")
    shadow_root1 = expand_root_element(root1)
    root2 = shadow_root1.find_element(By.ID, "container")
    root3 = root2.find_element(By.ID, "main")
    shadow_root3 = expand_root_element(root3)
    root4 = shadow_root3.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "showing-subpage")
    shadow_root4 = expand_root_element(root4)
    root5 = shadow_root4.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "settings-privacy-page")
    shadow_root5 = expand_root_element(root5)
    root6 = shadow_root5.find_element(By.ID, "pages")
    root7 = root6.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "settings-subpage")
    root8 = root7.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "site-details")
    shadow_root8 = expand_root_element(root8)
    root9 = shadow_root8.find_element(By.ID, "plugins")
    shadow_root9 = expand_root_element(root9)
    root10 = shadow_root9.find_element(By.ID, "permission")
    Select(root10).select_by_value("allow")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same answer as user BaiJiFeiLong

but i found that I had to change the line:

```
root5 = shadow_root4.find_element(By.ID, "advancedPage")
```

to:

```
root5 = shadow_root4.find_element(By.ID, "basicPage")
```

Because the original line was returning NoSuchElement error.