# No Flash reset Google Chrome v71 Selenium .Net

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, google-chrome, flash

I've got a problem with Flash reset after browser closure.
How can i make browser not to disable flash player after restarting browser?
These features doesn't work:

```
options.AddArgument("--disable-features=EnableEphemeralFlashPermission");

        // Enable Flash
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins", 1);
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player", 1);
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player", 1);
```

Comment: Problem is solved.Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638244/allow-flash-content-in-chrome-71-running-via-chromedriver)