# Enable flash in new Chrome browsers (since v71) using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, flash, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm developing automated tests for web application that requires Flash plugin. Starting from Chrome v71 it doesn't allow to enable Flash plugin from selenium.
The only way that I found is registry modification on Windows (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53707777/4579292)). 
How can I do the same on Ubuntu or maybe there is a way to enable flash from selenium webdriver?

Chromedrive: 2.46

Chrome version: 72.0.3626.96

The suggestions like adding the following preferences to ChromeOptions don't work since Chrom v71.

```
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins" => 1,
           "profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player" => 1,
           "profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player" => 1,
           "PluginsAllowedForUrls" => "hendricks-as3.localhost.bbc.co.uk"
          }
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I explained it in question.