# ChromeDriver FlashPolicyHelper does not work remotely

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, flash-selenium

We're using the

```
  new FlashPolicyHelper(driver).addSite("https://your.site")
```

In order to bypass the getFlash prompt when trying to navigate to our websites that use Flash.

However this does not seem to work when executed remotely.

Current Implementation

Calling the FlashPolicyHelper Class

```
if(browser.driver instanceof ChromeDriver)
    {
      new FlashPolicyHelper((ChromeDriver) browser.driver).addSite(odysseyURL)
    }
    browser


public class FlashPolicyHelper
{
private final ChromeDriver driver;

public FlashPolicyHelper(ChromeDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

public FlashPolicyHelper addSite(String site) {
    try {
        this.driver.get("chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=" + site);
... rest of code for FlashPolicyHelper found here...
```

[Allow Flash content in Chrome 69 running via chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185371/allow-flash-content-in-chrome-69-running-via-chromedriver)

Comment: Cross posted: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42068/chromedriver-flashpolicyhelper-does-not-work-remotely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I needed to instantiate a Remote Web Driver in order to have functionality remotely. Solved.

```
if(browser.driver instanceof RemoteWebDriver)
{
  new FlashPolicyHelper((RemoteWebDriver) browser.driver).addSite(odysseyURL)
}
browser


public class FlashPolicyHelper
{
private final RemoteWebDriver driver;

public FlashPolicyHelper(RemoteWebDriver driver) {
this.driver = driver;
}

public FlashPolicyHelper addSite(String site) {
try {
    this.driver.get("chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=" + site);
... rest of code for FlashPolicyHelper found here...
```

[Allow Flash content in Chrome 69 running via chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185371/allow-flash-content-in-chrome-69-running-via-chromedriver)